# Python Regex - Match if capture group does not contain a specific character

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a python regex that fails if a capture group contains a specific char.

At the moment this is my regex:

```
^/api/(?P<username>.+)/$
```

This regex accepts the following strings:

```
/api/test/      #Should match
/api/test/test/ #Should not match
```

However the capture group matches `test/test` as the username. I would like the regex to fail if "/" is encountered.

Comment: `^/api/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$`?

Comment: @coldspeed You may post an answer. It works. I am kinda new to regex's, forgot about the + sign...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to avoid any forward-slashes between the second and last one. You can use a character pattern to exclude it in matches:

```
^/api/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$
```

Where `[^/]+` will match one or more characters that do not consist of a forward-slash.